# Access remote SQL Server database using webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web-services

I have sql server database in my web project (hosted over the internet). Now, i want to make a c# windows forms (or WPF) application that, i can access the same database(that is in my web project).
What is the best way to make that application? Which webservice technique should i use.
Any help link regard to this will be appreciatable.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose your data through a public API implemented in WCF, and call that API from basically any kind of .NET application including  WinForms and WPF by using WCF as well. So, check out WCF ([Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324))

Comment: I was expecting this. Thanks for your help